# form enctype="multipart/form-data" is resulting in an ajax partial-response of validationFailed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Actually to overcome the [issue](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=507) of primefaces with fileuploader when STATE_SAVING_METHOD=client. I thought to make use of BalusC code as we use Servlet 3.0 posted [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html). The problem I am facing is when I click the submit button, I received an ajax partial reponse like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <partial-response>
    <changes>
     <update id="javax.faces.ViewState">
      <![CDATA[somejunk]]> 
     </update>
    </changes>
   <extension primefacesCallbackParam="validationFailed">{"validationFailed":false}</extension>
```

It never calls the decode method in FileRenderer.java. If I remove the enctype, it was calling decode method and obviously failing to cast to MultipartRequest on line:

```
 File file = ((MultipartRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest()).getFile(clientId);
```

Libraries:
PF 2.2.1
JSF 2.0.9

Comment: validationFailed  <--- do you have any validators in the form ? like required="true" on any fields near by ? are you trying to submit the form before filling some "must" fields ?

Comment: @Daniel I have used the same upload.xhtml as mentioned in the example and all are optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I switched from STATE_SAVING_METHOD=server to client. I forgot to remove the `org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter` in my web.xml. So the Primefaces `FileUploadFilter` was responding with a partial ajax response everytime. I removed it and it is working fine now.

@BalusC, Thanks for your wonderful code!